# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError is undefined

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I had a problem with this `jinja2.exception` and I was totally confused why. I wanted to post data to my `.html`, which I got from an API.

```
@app.route("/playerstats", methods = ["GET"])
def statsget():
    return render_template("stats.html")

@app.route("/playerstats", methods = ["POST"])
def statspost():
    player_uri = "https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?search={}%20{}"
    playerinput = request.form["nm"]
    player_split = playerinput.split()
    vn = player_split[0]
    nn = player_split[1]
    r = requests.get(player_uri.format(vn, nn)).json()

    data = {
        "player_id": r["data"][0]["id"],
        "player_first_name": r["data"][0]["first_name"]
    }

    return render_template("stats.html", data=data)
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="height: 40px; width: 450px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; border-width: 1px; border-color:lightgrey; text-align: start;">
    {{data.player_first_name}} {{data.player_id}}
</button>
```

Running the webpage put out this exception: `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError 'data' is undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to put the data I get from the api into an array and run a for-loop inside the html to give out all data:

inside main.py:

```
@app.route("/playerstats", methods = ["GET"])
def pstatsget():
    return render_template("stats.html")

@app.route("/playerstats", methods = ["POST"])
def pstatspost():
    player_uri = "https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?search={}%20{}"
    playerinput = request.form["nm"]
    player_split = playerinput.split()
    vn = player_split[0]
    nn = player_split[1]
    r = requests.get(player_uri.format(vn, nn)).json()

    data_group = []
    data = {
        "player_id": r["data"][0]["id"],
        "player_first_name": r["data"][0]["first_name"]
    }
    data_group.append(data)

    print(data_group)

    return render_template("stats.html", data=data_group)
```

inside stats.html:

```
{% for d in data: %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="height: 40px; width: 450px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; border-width: 1px; border-color:lightgrey; text-align: start;">
        {{d.player_first_name}} {{d.player_id}}
    </button>
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this works for you aswell!